# Money transfer from India to US scam

Tags: taxes, india, scams

The US bank BOA sent $6,000.00 to India to be sent to me in US. But India won't transfer the money to me until I pay $1,200.00 for taxes. I was told the FCAI will hold it till I do.

The funds are a refund that the Bank of America owes me.
I have paid income tax on that money. Is this legitimate or is this a scam?

Comment: If BOA owes you money (e.g. because you closed an account and are waiting for the check representing the balance to be sent to you), call them to find out why the money was sent to some bank in India instead of to you directly (regardless of where you actually are living). If _you_ gave BOA instructions to send the money to some bank in India, then you might need to live with the consequences.

Answer (score 8):

This is a scam.

Do you know why Bank of America is doing a refund? Did you own any accounts?

Why is India involved in this? If Bank of America in US wants to transfer money to you in US, India is not involved at all.

Stop all communications with the scammer and don't transfer any money.